# Pandas groupby and then count the occurrence of 0

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

From this table, I try to interpolate missing dates by the min/max weekly dates available in the dataframe. Then, calculate the occurrence of 0 sales for each category.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'category_id': ['aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa','bbb','bbb','bbb','ccc','ccc'],
                 'week': ['2015-01-05', '2015-01-12', '2015-01-19', '2015-01-26','2015-01-12', '2015-01-19', '2015-01-26','2015-01-05', '2015-01-12'],
                 'sales': [0,20,30,10,45,0,47,0,10]})
```

First step: Add missing weekly dates to all categories and fill 0 to missing dates (**Q1**: I'm not sure how to get this df_add_missing_dates result)

```
# expected dates interpolation output
df_add_missing_dates=pd.DataFrame({'category_id': ['aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa','bbb','bbb','bbb','bbb','ccc','ccc','ccc','ccc'],
                                   'week': ['2015-01-05', '2015-01-12', '2015-01-19', '2015-01-26',
                                            '2015-01-05', '2015-01-12', '2015-01-19', '2015-01-26',
                                            '2015-01-05', '2015-01-12', '2015-01-19', '2015-01-26'],
                                   'sales': [0,20,30,10,
                                             0,45,0,47,
                                             0,10,0,0]})
```

Second step: Count the occurrence of 0 weekly sales (**Q2**: How to aggregate the sales=0 for each category?)

```
# expected final output
category_id | sales_0_count
aaa         | 1
bbb         | 2
ccc         | 3
```

Current code and logics:

```
# convert string to datetime and set as index
df['week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['week'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
# find min/max weekly dates in the dataframe --> I couldn't add missing dates with 0 sales though
idx = pd.period_range(start=df.week.min(),end=df.week.max(),freq='W')
df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0).reset_index(drop=True)
df_add_missing_dates = df
# group by category to count how many times weekly sales is 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `pd.MultiIndex.from_products` with `reindex` and `fill_value = 0` then use a boolean matrix and `groupby` with `sum`:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['category_id'].unique(), 
                                  df['week'].unique()], 
                                 names=['category_id', 'week'])
df_missing = (df.set_index(['category_id', 'week'])
                .reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
                .reset_index())
df_missing
```

Output:

```
   category_id        week  sales
0          aaa  2015-01-05      0
1          aaa  2015-01-12     20
2          aaa  2015-01-19     30
3          aaa  2015-01-26     10
4          bbb  2015-01-05      0
5          bbb  2015-01-12     45
6          bbb  2015-01-19      0
7          bbb  2015-01-26     47
8          ccc  2015-01-05      0
9          ccc  2015-01-12     10
10         ccc  2015-01-19      0
11         ccc  2015-01-26      0
```

Now, group and sum:

```
(df_missing == 0).groupby(df_missing['category_id'])['sales'].sum()
```

Output:

```
category_id
aaa    1.0
bbb    2.0
ccc    3.0
Name: sales, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the reindex part is for, but after the

```
df['week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['week'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

you could do:

```
groupedDf = df.groupby(['category_id', pd.Grouper(key='week', freq='W-MON')])['sales'].sum().reset_index().sort_values('week')

zeroSalesWeek = groupedDf[groupedDf.sales == 0]
```

output:

```
zeroSalesWeek

    category_id   week        sales
0   aaa           2015-01-05    0
4   bbb           2015-01-05    0
8   ccc           2015-01-05    0
6   bbb           2015-01-19    0
10  ccc           2015-01-19    0
11  ccc           2015-01-26    0
```

to select a particular category_id you could try:

```
df[(df.sales == 0) & (df.category_id=='bbb')]
```

which would give you

```
    category_id   week        sales
4   bbb           2015-01-05    0
6   bbb           2015-01-19    0
```

Furthermore, if you think this may be a little too time consuming you can always create a quick function to select a particular category_id like:

```
def zeroGroupedDf(df, category_id):
    category_id = str(category_id)
    tempDf = df[(df.sales == 0) & (df.category_id==category_id)]
    return tempDf
```

and call any category_id you want to make a new df such as:

```
test = zeroGroupedDf(df, 'bbb')
test

    category_id   week        sales
4   bbb           2015-01-05    0
6   bbb           2015-01-19    0
```

Comment: Hi @Gorlomi I tried your solution but I couldn't get "bbb", "2015-01-05", 0 from the above Grouper and groupby code

Comment: Hi @Blair, when you say "couldnt get" you mean couldnt select? if that's the case i modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the expected output in a crude way:

```
df_add_missing_dates[df_add_missing_dates.sales.eq(0)].groupby('category_id')['sales'].count()
```

If you want the actual dataframe you expected (though this could be done much better):

```
expected_output = df_add_missing_dates[df_add_missing_dates.sales.eq(0)].\
    groupby('category_id',as_index=False)['sales'].count().\
    rename({'sales':'sales_0_count'},axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I don't know how to create the df_add_missing_dates table from df :(

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
dfz = df_add_missing_dates[df_add_missing_dates['sales']==0]
g = dfz.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='category_id'))
g['sales'].count()


category_id
aaa    1
bbb    2
ccc    3
Name: sales, dtype: int64
```